# Just top of the page is shown when using scrollView in ios

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, storyboard

I set scrollView for my view in storyboard. 
When I scroll, it shows a limited part of the page and the bottom of it is unreachable.
constraints are shown here:[image]

I also unchecked adjust scroll insets.

And the scrollbar is shown but it cannot do properly

Comment: Change your height constraints to some big (say 800) of scroll view ( in your case view below scroll view in above image) You will be able to see missing content , With this you may be able to locate your mistake, if not possible share your project so that i can help you

Comment: Follow this from scratch, and it'll work: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RV7vz4WSy7w